# complie a exploit that has a makefile

Tags: security, exploit

So it is 5:12am and I have been trying to figure this out for hours. I am a little new to the subject so please forgive the noob.

I download this exploit from http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/9301/ .. The problem is the program comes with two .c files and 2 .h files along with a makefile. Could anyone shed some light on how to complie this. I can't seem to find the information I am looking for.

BTW this is for a security course I am taking online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Type `make`. If you don't have make installed, you will need to install it (and in that case it is very likely you will also need to install a C compiler and its dependencies).